# Is it UNION, AND, OR?

Tags: mysql, union

I have tried all, is there another syntax that will work?  I have the following

```
SELECT  `ID` , `Home_Team`
FROM  `FixturesDates` where `ID` =
  (SELECT `ID` 
   FROM `FixturesDates` 
   WHERE `Home_Team`     
      REGEXP 'saturday|sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday' 
   order by ID asc LIMIT 1)
```

this works,

and I also have

```
SELECT  `ID` , `Home_Team`
FROM  `FixturesDates` 
where `ID` =
  (SELECT `ID` FROM `FixturesDates` WHERE `Home_Team`
   REGEXP 'saturday|sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday' 
   order by ID asc LIMIT 1,1)
```

this also works, but im unable to combine the 2 together,  have tried

```
SELECT  `ID` , `Home_Team`
FROM  `FixturesDates` 
where `ID` =
  (SELECT `ID` FROM `FixturesDates` WHERE `Home_Team`
   REGEXP 'saturday|sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday' 
   order by ID asc LIMIT 1)
UNION
  (SELECT `ID` FROM `FixturesDates` WHERE `Home_Team`
   REGEXP 'saturday|sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday' 
   order by ID asc LIMIT 1,1)
```

but this does not work, neither does AND, or OR.  is there something else that will?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine them because they have different columns.

Try adding `NULL` or `Home_Team` to the second subquery:

```
SELECT  `ID` , `Home_Team`
FROM  `FixturesDates` 
where `ID` =
  (SELECT `ID` FROM `FixturesDates` WHERE `Home_Team`
   REGEXP 'saturday|sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday' 
   order by ID asc LIMIT 1)
UNION
  (SELECT `ID`, NULL as Home_Team FROM `FixturesDates` WHERE `Home_Team`
   REGEXP 'saturday|sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday' 
   order by ID asc LIMIT 1,1)
```

Or, more simply:

```
SELECT  `ID` , `Home_Team`
FROM  `FixturesDates` 
where `ID` in
  (SELECT `ID` FROM `FixturesDates` WHERE `Home_Team`
   REGEXP 'saturday|sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday' 
   order by ID asc LIMIT 2)
```

This is based on the same query.  Perhaps you mean something like this:

```
SELECT  `ID` , `Home_Team`
FROM  `FixturesDates` 
where `ID` =
  (SELECT `ID` FROM `FixturesDates` WHERE `Home_Team`
   REGEXP 'saturday|sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday' 
   order by ID asc LIMIT 1)
  OR ID = 
  (SELECT `ID`, NULL as Home_Team FROM `FixturesDates` WHERE `Home_Team`
   REGEXP 'saturday|sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday' 
   order by ID asc LIMIT 1,1)
```

The proper union of your two original query would include both *full* queries:

```
SELECT  `ID` , `Home_Team`
FROM  `FixturesDates` where `ID` =
  (SELECT `ID` 
   FROM `FixturesDates` 
   WHERE `Home_Team`     
      REGEXP 'saturday|sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday' 
   order by ID asc LIMIT 1)
union 
SELECT  `ID` , `Home_Team`
FROM  `FixturesDates` 
where `ID` =
  (SELECT `ID` FROM `FixturesDates` WHERE `Home_Team`
   REGEXP 'saturday|sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday' 
   order by ID asc LIMIT 1,1)
```

Comment: The first one should work as the Column is not NULL, you can see that from running the second part of the query alone so I dont know why it is saying NULL, but the final query you posted worked perfect.  thank you

Comment: @Mike . . . I now realize that you intend to do the `union` within the `where` clause.  For this, you need an extra set of parens:  `where id in ((select . . .) union (select . . .))`.  The `union` is applying to the whole query.